# Core Data Join Table Many to Many Relationship - Object Creation

Tags: swift, join, core-data, many-to-many

I want to create a join table (BadgeProfile) for 2 entities: HubProfile & Badge. See pic below
[image]

**Issue 1:** I want to know how to create a "BadgeProfile" object. This object should map to one "HubProfile" and one "Badge" Object

**Issue 2:** Once the "BadgeProfile" object is created which can later be accessed by both "HubProfile" & "Badge". (example: HubProfile.BadgeProfile) How do I do that?

Below are the classes for the entities:

**HubProfile**

```
class HubProfile: NSManagedObject {
  @NSManaged var id: NSNumber?
  @NSManaged var name: String?
  @NSManaged var hubBadgeProfiles: NSOrderedSet?
}
```

**Badge**

```
class Badge: NSManagedObject {
  @NSManaged var id: NSNumber?
  @NSManaged var name: String?
  @NSManaged var score: NSNumber?
  @NSManaged var badgeProfiles: NSOrderedSet?
}
```

**BadgeProfile**

```
class BadgeProfile: NSManagedObject {
  @NSManaged var id: NSNumber?
  @NSManaged var badge: Badge?
  @NSManaged var hubProfile: HubProfile?
}
```

**P.S:** I am aware that I don't need to create a Join Table and can go with a **Many to Many** relationship between HubProfile <<-- -->> Badge. But I want to create the join table as it will make it very easy to interact with the backend DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found the solution:

**Creating Sample Objects:**

```
func loadBadgeProfilesPart2() //Second Way to Create BadgeProfile
{

    let hubProfileEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("HubProfile", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
    let hubProfile1 = HubProfile(entity: hubProfileEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
    hubProfile1.id = 5
    hubProfile1.name = "EFG"

    let badgeEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Badge", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
    let badge1 = Badge(entity: badgeEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
    badge1.id = 5
    badge1.name = "Polite"

    let badgeProfileEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("BadgeProfile", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
    let badgeProfile1 = BadgeProfile(entity: badgeProfileEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
    badgeProfile1.id = 3

    let badgeProfile2 = BadgeProfile(entity: badgeProfileEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
    badgeProfile2.id = 4

    let badgeProfileSet: NSMutableOrderedSet = []  //Add to an NSOrderedSet
    badgeProfileSet.addObject(badgeProfile1)
    badgeProfileSet.addObject(badgeProfile2)

    hubProfile1.hubBadgeProfiles = badgeProfileSet //Assign BadgeProfile to HubProfile
    badge1.badgeProfiles = badgeProfileSet //Assign BadgeProfile to Badge

    do
    {
        try! self.managedContext.save()
    }

}
```

**Fetching the Objects in TableView**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! BadgeProfileViewCell!
    configureCell(cell, indexPath: indexPath)
    return cell
}

func configureCell(cell: BadgeProfileViewCell, indexPath: NSIndexPath) //Showing in TableView
{
    let badgeProfile = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! BadgeProfile
    cell.nameLabel?.text = badgeProfile.hubProfile?.name
    cell.badgeLabel?.text = badgeProfile.badge?.name
}
```

This seems to be working.

Comment: This is essentially my solution, just with the ordered set.

Answer (score 1):

#### To create the join table object:

Create it the same way you would create any other entity, e.g. via

```
NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(...)
```

Then just add the objects you want to link.

```
badgeProfile.hubProfile = hubProfile
badgeProfile.badge = badge
```

I would advise not to use ordered sets. They are complicated and error prone. The above, for example, becomes a real headache. Instead, use a number attribute in the `BadgeProfile` entity to keep track of the order yourself.

#### To access the joined object

Nothing special here. Get all badges for a profile:

```
profile.hubBadgeProfiles.map { $0.badge! }
```

(I think your attribute name is poorly chosen. I suggest `badges`, and the equivalent on the other side, `profiles` for the `Badge` entity.)

Get a specific badge:

```
profile.badges.filter { $0.badge!.name == "Gold" }.first as? Badge
```

Use the analog pattern to go in the other direction.

Comment: thanks for this. I have 3 questions: 1) when I create the one to many relationship should I not tick the orderedSet column 2) didnt quite understand what the number attribute in the BadgeProfile will do 3) what does ".map{ $0.badge!}" do

Comment: OK, if you prefer ordered sets you can continue using them. I can research how to set the relationship then. - The `map` closure *replaces* the elements in the set (join entities) with their corresponding badges. The `!` implies that we are sure this relationship is never `nil`.

Comment: Hi Mundi..I have posted a solution -- can you please see if this makes sense and is right..Its working for me but I am not aware if it will lead to any problems later on